# Uploadifive - allowed file types like uploadifty

Tags: jquery, uploadify

With uploadify I could set the allowed file types like

```
'fileType' : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.jpeg;',
```

and it would display in the dialog box `All files(*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.jpeg;)`

Is there anyway in uploadifive to get it to work exactly like this, I have used various options that I have found in the forum and the closest I have got is from this [thread](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/9102/use-html5-access-attribute/p1)
code below:

```
'fileType'  : ["image\/gif","image\/jpeg","image\/png","image\/jpg", "application\/pdf"],',


var accept_types = '';
if(typeof settings.fileType !== 'object'){
  settings.fileType = [settings.fileType];
}
for (var i=0;i<settings.fileType.length;i++){
   var filetype_match = /^([a-z0-9]+)$/g.exec(settings.fileType[i]);
     if(filetype_match != null){
         accept_types += filetype_match[1]+'/*,';
    }else{
         accept_types += settings.fileType[i]+',';
    }
}
accept_types = accept_types.slice(0,accept_types.length-1);
if(accept_types.length > 0){
   input.attr('accept', accept_types);
}                   


 // Check the filetype
                if (settings.fileType) {
                    if ($.isArray(settings.fileType)) {
                        var isValidFileType = 0;
                        for (var n = 0; n < settings.fileType.length; n++) {
                            if (file.type.indexOf(settings.fileType[n]) > -1) {
                                alert(isValidFileType + 'valid file');
                                isValidFileType = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!isValidFileType) {
                            alert(isValidFileType + 'not validid');
                            alert(settings.fileType);
                            $data.error('FORBIDDEN_FILE_TYPE', file);

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (file.type.indexOf(settings.fileType) < 0) {

                            $data.error('FORBIDDEN_FILE_TYPE', file);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This works great, however by default it still displays "All files(*.*)" as default with the option to select the allowed files from the drop down.

ideally I would like it to look something like "All supported files types (.pdf, .jpeg)" etc to appear as the default

I do not like the functionality that the forbidden file types uses as I want my users to see what files they can upload and not gamble on a click only for it to say forbidden file etc

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

there is fileDesc parameter where you can give your custom text

$('#fileInput').uploadify({

'fileDesc': 'All supported files types (.pdf, .jpeg)',

});

If this answer was helpful.Dont forget to mark as answer

Thanks
AB

Comment: Hi sorry AB it appears some other user edited my post and changed everything that said uploadifive to uploadfiy..... I need help with uploadifive (HTML5) not Uploadify (flash) I do not have sufficient rep score to post with the tag uploadifive, however your post is correct but it is not what I am after, as this will just change the actual text and things however I need the functionality of allowed file types like uploadify uses for uploadifive as it does things differently

Answer (score 0):

The *Filetype* you want to upload should be setted in *uploadifive.php* file, it's a array, you may set it like this:

```
 //Set the allowed file extensions
 $fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'rar', 'zip');
```

And at the *demo* page you can also set the *fileType* you want user to upload, just do it like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
      $('#imageFile_new').uploadifive({
        'auto'             : false,
        'fileType'         : new Array("image","application"),
        'truncateLength'   : '15',
        'checkScript'      : '/check-exists.php',
        'formData'         : {
                                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                              },
         'queueID'          : 'drop_zone',
         'uploadScript'     : '/uploadifive.php',
         'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
       });
    });
</script>
```